# How to send broadcast message to users using tigase

Tags: push, message, broadcast, tigase

I met a problem in my project.I used tigase to push message to android client,but sometimes we should push more than 1000 users's notices at one time . Using smack api to implement this is too slow .Is  anyone has new method to do this ? Can I add a http api to send broadcast message using tigase ?

Answer (score 0):

There is REST API available in Tigase but why do you think it would be faster than using XMPP?
This actually depends on how you do this. Using admin ad-hoc commands (either via standard XMPP or REST API) you can submit 1000 or more notices with a single call. Assuming you have a list of all recipients beforehand. You can also send a message to all online users with a single admin ad-hoc command.

Or maybe what you do is actually a job for a PubSub component?

Comment: “Using admin ad-hoc commands (either via standard XMPP or REST API) you can submit 1000 or more notices with a single call. ” can you describe it in detail ?I  want to implement this ,but I can't find any information about it .Can I do it use smack or the tigase client api ?

Comment: @Arthur Hefczyc, could you describe it in detail?